# Binding to observable collection, dependency property fails

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, dependency-properties, invocationtargetexception

I have a usercontrol where I need a list of a simple class I've made, called Person:

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the usercontrol, I need to have a ObservableCollection<Person> that I can bind to. So I figure I need to make it a dependency property. So in the usercontrol I have the following:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonsDependencyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Persons", typeof(ObservableCollection<Person>),
                                typeof(PersonUserControl));
```

And the property is like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
{
   get
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<Person>)GetValue(PersonsDependencyProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(PersonsDependencyProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Now in my MainWindow.xaml codebehind I make an ObservableCollection<Person> called PersonList, set the mainwindow datacontext to self, and bind to it like so:

```
<Local:PersonUserControl Persons="{Binding PersonList}">
</Local:PersonUserControl>
```

And I get the error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. - No further explanation. Can anybody tell me how to react to it or what I'm doing wrong.

I hope I'm being clear enough.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace and also it inner exceptions if any? By the way you should name your property as `PersonsProperty` so it should be `public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonsDependencyProperty`

Comment: Can you please show your xaml.cs file code

Answer (score 0):

`PersonsDependencyProperty` should be just `PersonsProperty`. Hard to say whether that's the underlying cause without more information, but that's certainly a problem. WPF appends "Property" onto the binding path in order to find the related dependency property. Thus, it won't find yours.